# Why would curl_global_sslset() return CURLSSLSET_TOO_LATE even if it is called before curl_global_init()?

Tags: cygwin, libcurl

I am trying to develop a an application that uses a RESTful API to a server through SSL. I came across [this example](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/sslbackend.html), but I cannot get it to run.

I shortened it to this example below. It compiles and runs, but the return from the call to *curl_global_sslset()* is 2 (CURLSSLSET_TOO_LATE) rather than CURLSSLSET_UNKNOWN_BACKEND.

Note that I have not made a call to *curl_global_init()*. According to the libcurl documentation for *curl_global_sslset()*:

> If the backend had been configured previously, or if curl_global_init
>   has already been called, the function returns CURLSSLSET_TOO_LATE.

I am compiling and running on 64-bit Cygwin installed on Windows 7. Outputs of *curl-config --version* and *curl-config --features* appear below the code.

Why is this happening, and what can be done to fix it?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <curl/curl.h>

/*
 * An SSL-enabled libcurl is required for this sample to work (at least one
 * SSL backend has to be configured).
 *
 *  **** This example only works with libcurl 7.56.0 and later! ****
*/

int main(void)
{
    CURLsslset result;
    const curl_ssl_backend **list;
    int i;

    result = curl_global_sslset(-1, NULL, &list);
    if (result == CURLSSLSET_UNKNOWN_BACKEND) {
        for(i = 0; list[i]; i++) {
            printf("SSL backend #%d: '%s' (ID: %d)\n",
                        i, list[i]->name, list[i]->id);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("curl_global_sslset returns %d\n", result);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Curl-config outputs:

```
$ curl-config --version
libcurl 7.59.0


$ curl-config --features
SSL
IPv6
UnixSockets
libz
AsynchDNS
IDN
GSS-API
PSL
SPNEGO
Kerberos
NTLM
NTLM_WB
TLS-SRP
HTTP2
HTTPS-proxy
```

Comment: I can't explain that. It doesn't happen for me on Linux. I would recommend using a debugger to figure it out as it sounds like possibly a bug...